# Why is my route not directing to my page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes

I have a ASP.NET web forms project, with the following routes. This usually works fine, but I cannot get the last one to work:

```
static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapPageRoute("Sidevisning",
                        "{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.Article + "}",
                        "~/ArticleLayout.aspx");



    routes.MapPageRoute("Tags",
                        "tags/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.Tags + "}",
                        "~/TagsPage.aspx");

    routes.MapPageRoute("Forumpost",
                        "forums/topic/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.Post + "}",
                        "~/ForumPost.aspx");

    routes.MapPageRoute("Bruger",
                        "users/{" +
                        Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.UserProfileId + "}",
                        "~/UserProfile.aspx");

    routes.MapPageRoute("Offer",
                        "offers/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.OfferForm + "}",
                        "~/Offer.aspx");


    routes.MapPageRoute("Ret opgaver",
                        "assignments/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.Assignment + "}",
                        "~/ReviewAssignments.aspx");


    routes.MapPageRoute("Tutoring with subject",
                        "tutoring/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.TutorSubject + "}",
                        "~/tutoring/tutors.aspx");

    routes.MapPageRoute("Tutoring with subject and city",
                        "tutoring/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.TutorSubject + "}/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.TutorCity + "}",
                        "~/tutoring/tutors.aspx");

    routes.MapPageRoute("Tutoring with subject, city and level",
                        "tutoring/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.TutorSubject + "}/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.TutorCity + "}/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.TutorLevel + "}",
                        "~/tutoring/tutors.aspx");


    routes.MapPageRoute("Blog kategori",
                "category/{BlogCategoryName}",
                "~/BlogCategory.aspx");



    // be careful to switch around , it might give some pretty fucked up errors



    routes.MapPageRoute("Laes Blog",
        "{Year}/{Month}/{BlogHeadline}",
        "~/ReadBlogEntry.aspx");


    routes.MapPageRoute("Subject details",
                  "subject/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.SubjectChosen + "}/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.SubjectAction + "}",
                  "~/SubjectDetails.aspx");


}
```

So when I enter a URL, like:

```
http://localhost:5744/subject/danskundervisning/articleoverview
```

I want to hit SubjectDetails.aspx.

However, instead I hit some other page and redirected to my front page. I cannot find out WHAT page I am hitting either, which is kind of annoying.

From these sparse info, is there something which looks wrong in my routes? Shouldn't the last one work when I enter the URL i wrote?

I don't think it has any interest, but here is my RouteVaraibles:

```
 public class RouteVariables
        {
            public const string Article = "article";
            public const string OfferForm = "offers";
            public const string Forumcategory = "forumname";
            public const string Post = "posturl";
            public const string UserProfileId = "userid";
            public const string UserProfileProfilename = "userprofilename";
            public const string Tags = "tags";
            public const string Assignment = "assignment";
            public const string TutorSubject = "tutorsubject";
            public const string TutorCity = "tutorcity";
            public const string TutorLevel = "tutorlevel";

            public const string SubjectAction = "subjectionaction";

            public const string SubjectChosen = "subjectchosen";


        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the routes is important.
You are always going to be redirected to LaesBlog Route.
So you need to put that one last like this

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Subject details",
              "subject/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.SubjectChosen + "}/{" + Utils.Constants.RouteVariables.SubjectAction + "}",
              "~/SubjectDetails.aspx");

routes.MapPageRoute("Laes Blog",
    "{Year}/{Month}/{BlogHeadline}",
    "~/ReadBlogEntry.aspx");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Just made the change, and it worked. A BIG virtual high-five to you!

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. I changed the order of the route definition and it worked. The issue here is that Route "Laes Blog" has all dynamic parameters while route "Subject Details" has one static (hard-coded) parameter and 2 dynamic params. But both have 3 params, so it will be conflicted.

To conclude, always write routes without any static params, at the last.

I recently posted an article on my blog for the same issue at the following Link

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/10/url-routing-in-aspnet-web-forms-same.html

I have also posted other issues which I faced in implementing URL Routing in my previous blog posts.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).